# Listing only the last version of a row in a composite key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, composite-primary-key

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how composite keys are supposed to work with Entity Framework or SQL in general.

This is how my table looks like:

```
COD_ITEM    COD_ITEM_VERSION    ITEM_NAME
1           1                   A
1           2                   A
1           3                   A
2           1                   A
2           2                   A
2           3                   A
2           4                   A
2           5                   A
3           1                   A
```

I need to list those items, but only the last version of each one... so I'd have this output:

```
COD_ITEM    COD_ITEM_VERSION    ITEM_NAME
1           3                   A
2           5                   A
3           1                   A
```

I tried this but it didn't work, and it throws an error if the table is empty.

```
db.T_ITEMS.GroupBy(r => r.COD_ITEM).Last().ToList();
```

How can I do this? My mind is completely blank right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking this:

```
var result=db.T_ITEMS.GroupBy(r => r.COD_ITEM)
                     .Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(r=>r.COD_ITEM_VERSION).FirstOrDefault())
                     .ToList();
```

After you group, order by (in descending order) `COD_ITEM_VERSION` each group to get just the last one